# Android - Grouping Received Push Notifications like Gmail

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications, grouping

I wants to group multiple push notifications received to My app like Gmail.
below picture will describe the requirement.
[image]

I have gone through many tutorials including developers website https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/group

But no luck. all the Received notifications are displaying as individual notification.

Below is my code snippet.

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
    // put the new message onto the event bus so that interested activities can subscribe to it
    // TODO[tim] we should probably look at the content of the message and send different events
    // onto the bus for different message types.

    int notificationId = (int) SystemClock.currentThreadTimeMillis();

    createNotificationChannel();

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext, ANDROID_CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher) // notification icon
            .setContentTitle(getTitle()) // title
            .setContentText("Vyn processed and ready to play") // body message
            .setContentIntent(getVynPlayIntent(getIntentExtraValues(), notificationId))
            .setAutoCancel(true) // clear notification when clicked
            .setGroup(GROUP_KEY_VYNS)
            .setGroupSummary(true)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);

    if (builder != null) {
        getManager().notify(notificationId, builder.build());
    }
}

private static final String ANDROID_CHANNEL_ID = "notifications.ANDROID_CHANNEL_ID";
private static final String GROUP_KEY_VYNS = "notifications.GROUP_KEY_VYNS";
private void createNotificationChannel() {
    // Create the NotificationChannel, but only on API 26+ because
    // the NotificationChannel class is new and not in the support library
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        CharSequence name = "channel_name";
        String description = "channel_description";
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(ANDROID_CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
        channel.setDescription(description);
        // Register the channel with the system; you can't change the importance
        // or other notification behaviors after this
        getManager().createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
}

private NotificationManagerCompat mManagerCompat;
public NotificationManagerCompat getManager() {
    if (mManagerCompat == null) {
        mManagerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(mContext);
    }
    return mManagerCompat;
}
```

Please help me finding whats missed in this code, if you identify.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling to `.setGroupSummary(true)` for every notification from the looks of it?

Only the actual summary notification should set that. The children should either omit it or set it to `false`

The Group Summary is the for what it shows when the notification is not expanded (the first screenshot in your question). All of the "children" notifications should be .setGroupSummary(false) or just not set at all (omit it)

You will want to make sure you have an overall group summary and call `notify` with its own ID.

From [this developer.android article](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/group)

```java
//use constant ID for notification used as group summary
int SUMMARY_ID = 0;
String GROUP_KEY_WORK_EMAIL = "com.android.example.WORK_EMAIL";

Notification newMessageNotification1 =
    new NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.this, CHANNEL_ID)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notify_email_status)
        .setContentTitle(emailObject1.getSummary())
        .setContentText("You will not believe...")
        .setGroup(GROUP_KEY_WORK_EMAIL) //**Note here that this is a "child" and does not call setGroupSummary(true)**
        .build();

Notification newMessageNotification2 =
    new NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.this, CHANNEL_ID)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notify_email_status)
        .setContentTitle(emailObject2.getSummary())
        .setContentText("Please join us to celebrate the...")
        .setGroup(GROUP_KEY_WORK_EMAIL) //**Note here that this is a "child" and does not call setGroupSummary(true)**
        .build();

Notification summaryNotification =
    new NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.this, CHANNEL_ID)
        .setContentTitle(emailObject.getSummary())
        //set content text to support devices running API level < 24
        .setContentText("Two new messages")
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notify_summary_status)
        //build summary info into InboxStyle template
        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle()
                .addLine("Alex Faarborg  Check this out")
                .addLine("Jeff Chang    Launch Party")
                .setBigContentTitle("2 new messages")
                .setSummaryText("janedoe@example.com"))
        //specify which group this notification belongs to
        .setGroup(GROUP_KEY_WORK_EMAIL)
        //set this notification as the summary for the group
        .setGroupSummary(true) //**Note here that this is the "parent" or the actual Group Summary and DOES call setGroupSummary(true)**
        .build();

NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
notificationManager.notify(emailNotificationId1, newMessageNotification1);
notificationManager.notify(emailNotificationId2, newMessageNotification2);
notificationManager.notify(SUMMARY_ID, summaryNotification);
```